# Gradient texture has wrong scale on retina Mac

Tags: macos, scale, sprite-kit, retina

I wrote a gradient generating function as a category on SKTexture. It works well on 1x screens but retina renders the texture too big, double width and double height ie wrong scale. I have been trying to get it right by changing between pixels and points, but can't get it right. Can someone help me please?

```
+(SKTexture*)gradientWithSize:(const CGSize)SIZE colors:(NSArray*)colors {
    // Hopefully this function would be platform independent one day.

    // Correct way to find scale?
    DLog(@"backingScaleFactor: %f", [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor]);
    const CGFloat SCALE = [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor];
    //const size_t WIDTH_PIXELS = SIZE.width * SCALE;
    //const size_t HEIGHT_PIXELS = SIZE.height * SCALE;
    CGContextRef cgcontextref = MyCreateBitmapContext(SIZE.width, SIZE.height, SCALE);
    NSAssert(cgcontextref != NULL, @"Failed creating context!");
    //  CGBitmapContextCreate(
    //                                                    NULL, // let the OS handle the memory
    //                                                    WIDTH_PIXELS,
    //                                                    HEIGHT_PIXELS,

    CAGradientLayer* gradient = CAGradientLayer.layer;
    //gradient.contentsScale = SCALE;
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SIZE.width, SIZE.height);

    NSMutableArray* convertedcolors = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (SKColor* skcolor in colors) {
        [convertedcolors addObject:(id)skcolor.CGColor];
    }
    gradient.colors = convertedcolors;
    [gradient renderInContext:cgcontextref];

    CGImageRef imageref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cgcontextref);
    DLog(@"imageref pixel size: %zu %zu", CGImageGetWidth(imageref), CGImageGetHeight(imageref));

    SKTexture* texture1 = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:imageref];
    DLog(@"size of gradient texture: %@", NSStringFromSize(texture1.size));

    CGImageRelease(imageref);

    CGContextRelease(cgcontextref);

    return texture1;
}
CGContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext(const size_t POINTS_W, const size_t POINTS_H, const CGFloat SCALE) {
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    //int             bitmapByteCount;
    size_t             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    const size_t PIXELS_W = POINTS_W * SCALE;
    const size_t PIXELS_H = POINTS_H * SCALE;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (PIXELS_W * 4);// 1
    //bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);// 2
    bitmapData = NULL;

#define kBitmapInfo     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    //#define kBitmapInfo       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
    //#define kBitmapInfo       kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    // According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18921840/129202 it should be safe to just cast
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapinfo = (CGBitmapInfo)kBitmapInfo; //kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst; //0; //kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask; //kCGImageAlphaNone; //kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,// 4
                                     PIXELS_W,
                                     PIXELS_H,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     bitmapinfo
                                     );
    if (context == NULL) {
        free (bitmapData);// 5
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );// 6

    // TEST!!
//  CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, POINTS_W, POINTS_H));
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, PIXELS_W, PIXELS_H));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, SCALE, SCALE);

    return context;// 7
}
```

So, to some sum it up, I expect to call `+(SKTexture*)gradientWithSize:(const CGSize)SIZE colors:(NSArray*)colors` using points for SIZE.

Comment: have you tried not scaling at all? Perhaps the bitmap automatically becomes retina sized on retina devices, as hinted by this question's accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867767/how-to-create-a-cgbitmapcontext-which-works-for-retina-display-and-not-wasting-s

Comment: Look at this Johnny, multiplying the points ect by the correct scale, it appears you could create UIImage from that, and give it a correct scale, but I don't know if you can do that in OSX? Anyways look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707465/coregraphics-for-retina-display

Comment: LearnCocos2D: thanks, I added an answer based on your suggestion. Not sure it is 100% correct however.

AwDogsGo2Heaven: Sorry, can't use UIImage because I used this for Mac. The closest thing to a shared image format we can get on these platforms is CGImageRef I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code as below based on LearnCocos2D's suggestion. When to scale and not to is confusing (because in the docs, `CGBitmapContextCreate` explicitly takes width and height in **PIXELS**) but this seems to have the size right also on retina screens. Still I don't know if the rendered resolution is really retina - but this is very hard to confirm using eye because after all this is a gradient... Still I'm using the same context creating functions for a texture repeater (to enable to use [colorWithPatternImage with Sprite Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490970/sprite-kit-and-colorwithpatternimage)). Maybe I have the time later to try a detailed texture repeated using this new version...
Also leaving `gradient.contentsScale = SCALE;` on or off doesn't make a visible difference.

```
+(SKTexture*)gradientWithSize:(const CGSize)SIZE colors:(NSArray*)colors {
    // Hopefully this function would be platform independent one day.

    CGContextRef cgcontextref = MyCreateBitmapContext(SIZE.width, SIZE.height);
    NSAssert(cgcontextref != NULL, @"Failed creating context!");

    CAGradientLayer* gradient = CAGradientLayer.layer;
    DLog(@"gradient.contentScale: %f", gradient.contentsScale);
    //gradient.contentsScale = SCALE;
    DLog(@"gradient.contentScale: %f", gradient.contentsScale);
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SIZE.width, SIZE.height);

    NSMutableArray* convertedcolors = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (SKColor* skcolor in colors) {
        [convertedcolors addObject:(id)skcolor.CGColor];
    }
    gradient.colors = convertedcolors;
    [gradient renderInContext:cgcontextref];

    CGImageRef imageref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cgcontextref);
    DLog(@"imageref pixel size: %zu %zu", CGImageGetWidth(imageref), CGImageGetHeight(imageref));

    SKTexture* texture1 = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:imageref];
    DLog(@"size of gradient texture: %@", NSStringFromSize(texture1.size));

    CGImageRelease(imageref);

    CGContextRelease(cgcontextref);

    return texture1;
}
CGContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext(const size_t POINTS_W, const size_t POINTS_H/*, const CGFloat SCALE*/) {
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    size_t             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (POINTS_W * 4);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    bitmapData = NULL;

#define kBitmapInfo     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    // According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18921840/129202 it should be safe to just cast
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapinfo = (CGBitmapInfo)kBitmapInfo;
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     POINTS_W,
                                     POINTS_H,
                                     8,
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     bitmapinfo
                                     );
    if (context == NULL) {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return context;
}
```

Results below. The left is just a yellow rectangle created using SKSpriteNode. The right is a rectangle created by using the texture generated from the above function. The two rectangles are at the same position and have same point sizes, just different anchorPoints.

```
SKColor* color1 = SKColor.blueColor;
SKColor* color2 = [SKColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
SKTexture* textureGradient = [SKTexture gradientWithSize:SIZE colors:@[color1, color2]];
SKSpriteNode* spriteGradient = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:textureGradient];
```

**1x resolution**
[image: Gradient 1x resolution]

**2x resolution (retina)**
[image: Gradient 2x resolution]