# iOS - Detect tap on specific portion of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I want to check if user tapped on white or black portion of below image.

I can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` or `hitTest:withEvent` method to get touch position. But not sure if that position is in black or white portion.

[image]

I am actually looking for a generic solution that can be used on any other image. Like we could know if user clicked on Africa or UAE in below image.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770181/how-to-get-the-pixel-color-on-touch