# Compare two UIColors (tap location in UIImageView vs assets catalog color)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicolor, cgcolorspace

I need to tap on an `UIImageView` ...

[image: hotspots]

... and compare the color of a tap location with a color returned from an assets catalog (or a custom color created in the code).

I am having lots of trouble with color spaces and my matches always being no. I have read some great examples on stackoverflow and have tried them, but I must still be doing something wrong.

- I use the [colorpicker from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770723/581190)
- [Variations of these two Objective-C answers for matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970475/how-to-compare-uicolors)

I have also tried to use custom colors like this (instead of asset colors):

```c
+ (UIColor *)themeRed {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:192.0f/255.0f green:92.0f/255.0f blue:42.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
}
```

Still no matches. My code for testing matches follows:

```c
-(void)tappedColorView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [tapRecognizer locationInView: uiiv_hs];
    //NSLog(@"my color %@", [uiiv_hs colorOfPoint:touchPoint]);

    UIColor *color = [uiiv_hs colorOfPoint:touchPoint];
    NSLog(@"color %@",[uiiv_hs colorOfPoint:touchPoint]);
    UIColor *matchcolor = [UIColor themeRed];
    NSLog(@"mcolor %@",[UIColor themeRed]);

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor colorNamed:@"Color01"],[UIColor colorNamed:@"Color02"], nil];

    if ([color matchesColor:matchcolor error:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"1Match!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"1No Match!");
    }

    if ([color isEqualToColor:[UIColor themeRed]]) {
        NSLog(@"2Match!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"2No Match!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this if you're not familiar with the following topics. I'm going to show you one way, a very simplified one, but there will be gotchas.

### Resources

Something to read upfront or at least be aware/familiar with it.

- Color related

  - [Color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space)
  - [Color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference)
  - [Color management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management) (especially [Color transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management#Color_transformation))
  - [WWDC 2017 - 821 - Get Started with Display P3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/821/)
- Float related

  - [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

### Problem #1 - Which color do you want?

Your `UIImageView` can be fully opaque, transparent, partially opaque, transparent, ... Let's say that there's a view with yellow color below the `UIImageView` and the `UIImageView` isn't opaque and alpha is set to 50%. What color do you want? Original image color? Rendered color (mixed with the yellow one)?

[image: Comparison of colors from UIView with different alpha channel]

I assume the one mixed with the yellow. Here's the code to get the right color.

Objective-C:

```c
@interface UIView(ColorAtPoint)

- (UIColor *)colorAt:(CGPoint)point;

@end

@implementation UIView(ColorAtPoint)

- (UIColor *)colorAt:(CGPoint)point {
    UIView *targetOpaqueView = self;

    while (!targetOpaqueView.isOpaque && targetOpaqueView.superview != nil) {
        targetOpaqueView = targetOpaqueView.superview;
    }

    CGPoint targetPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:targetOpaqueView];

    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    if (context == NULL) {
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return nil;
    }

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -targetPoint.x, -targetPoint.y);
    [targetOpaqueView.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0
                                     green:pixel[1]/255.0
                                      blue:pixel[2]/255.0
                                     alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color;
}

@end
```

Swift:

```swift
extension UIView {
    func color(at point: CGPoint) -> UIColor? {
        var targetOpaqueView: UIView = self

        // Traverse the view hierarchy to find a parent which is opaque
        while !targetOpaqueView.isOpaque && targetOpaqueView.superview != nil {
            targetOpaqueView = targetOpaqueView.superview!
        }

        // Convert the point from our view to the target one
        let targetPoint: CGPoint = convert(point, to: targetOpaqueView)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        var pixel: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        guard let context = CGContext(data: &pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }

        context.translateBy(x: -targetPoint.x, y: -targetPoint.y)

        // Render the target opaque view to get all the possible transparency right
        targetOpaqueView.layer.render(in: context)
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(pixel[0])/255.0, green: CGFloat(pixel[1])/255.0, blue: CGFloat(pixel[2])/255.0, alpha: CGFloat(pixel[3])/255.0)
    }
}
```

This function should return a color with alpha component set to `1.0`. It has to be `1.0` otherwise we can't continue. Why? Imagine that the `UIImageView` alpha is set to 50% -> we wont traverse the view hierarchy (this `targetOpaqueView` dance) -> we will get a color with alpha component close to `0.5` -> not of any use, what's below? White? Black? Orange?

### Problem #2 - Device

Every device is different and can display different range of colors - iPads, iPhones, ... This also includes other device types like computer displays, printers, ... Because I don't know what are you trying to achieve in your application, take it as a reminder - same color, but different look on every device.

### Problem #3 - Color profile

Here's the comparison of the Display P3 profile and Generic sRGB. You can compare more profiles just by launching ColorSync Utility on your macOS. It demonstrates that the color will differ when you convert a color from one space to another one.

[image: Display P3 and Generic sRGBP comparison]

### Problem #4 - Color conversion

Quotes from the [Color transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management#Color_transformation) chapter:

> Color transformation, or color space conversion, is the transformation of the representation of a color from one color space to another.
>
> &
>
> In nearly every translation process, we have to deal with the fact that the color gamut of different devices vary in range which makes an accurate reproduction impossible.

This is sort of complicated process, but it depends on many things (color spaces, ...). It can involve posterization (16-bit -> 8-bit for example), it depends on your rendering intent (relative colorimetric, perceptual, ...), etc.

Very simplified example - you have an image with red color (`#FF0000`) and there's Generic sRGB profile assigned to it. iPhone is going to display it (P3) and you'll see *different* color. More precisely, if you get RGB component values, they'll differ.

CoreGraphics.framework provides color conversion function - [`converted(to:intent:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/1455493-converted). You have to pass:

- the destination color space,
- intent = the mechanism to use to match the color when the color is outside the gamut of the new color space,
- options (just pass `nil`).

Objective-C:

```c
@interface UIColor(ColorSpaceConversion)

- (UIColor *)convertedToColorSpace:(CGColorSpaceRef)colorSpace;
- (UIColor *)convertedToColorSpace:(CGColorSpaceRef)colorSpace inten:(CGColorRenderingIntent)intent;

@end

@implementation UIColor(ColorSpaceConversion)

- (UIColor *)convertedToColorSpace:(CGColorSpaceRef)colorSpace {
    return [self convertedToColorSpace:colorSpace inten:kCGRenderingIntentDefault];
}

- (UIColor *)convertedToColorSpace:(CGColorSpaceRef)colorSpace inten:(CGColorRenderingIntent)intent {
    CGColorRef converted = CGColorCreateCopyByMatchingToColorSpace(colorSpace, intent, self.CGColor, NULL);

    if (converted == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithCGColor:converted];
    CGColorRelease(converted);
    return color;
}

@end
```

Swift:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    func converted(toColorSpace colorSpace: CGColorSpace, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent = .defaultIntent) -> UIColor? {
        guard let converted = cgColor.converted(to: colorSpace, intent: intent, options: nil) else {
            return nil
        }

        return UIColor(cgColor: converted)
    }
}
```

An example:

- Component values (RGBA) of the Extended sRGB color (`#CC3333`): 0.8 0.2 0.2 1
- Same color converted to Extended Linear sRGB: 0.603827 0.0331048 0.0331048 1
- Same color converted to Display P3: 0.737027 0.252869 0.228974 1

### Problem #5 - Custom color

You can create colors to compare against in two ways:

- Xcode assets catalog
- `UIColor` initializer

Xcode assets catalog allows you to specify color for different devices, gamuts or you can select custom content (Display P3, sRGB, Extended Range sRGB, ...).

`UIColor` initializer allows you to specify color in (not just):

- Display P3
- Extended Range sRGB (iOS >= 10)

Be aware how do you create a color to compare against. RGB component values differ in various color spaces.

### Problem #6 - Color comparison

As you are aware of how it works now, you can see that there's some math involved in a way that the converted color won't precisely match. I mean - two colors, converted to the same color space - you can't still compare components (RGB) with simple equality operator. Precision is lost due to conversion and even if not - remember [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

There's a way how to achieve what you want and it's called [Color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference). In other words - you'd like to calculate two colors distance.

Objective-C:

```c
@interface UIColor(EuclideanDistance)

- (CGFloat)euclideanDistanceTo:(UIColor *)other;

@end

@implementation UIColor(EuclideanDistance)

- (CGFloat)euclideanDistanceTo:(UIColor *)other {
    CIColor *ciColor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:self];
    CIColor *ciColorOther = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:other];

    if (ciColor.numberOfComponents != ciColor.numberOfComponents) {
        NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException
                                                         reason:@"Colors differ in numberOfComponents"
                                                       userInfo:nil];
        @throw exception;
    }

    if (ciColor.alpha != 1.0 || ciColorOther.alpha != 1.0) {
        NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException
                                                         reason:@"Transparent colors are not supported"
                                                       userInfo:nil];
        @throw exception;
    }

    CGFloat dr = ciColorOther.red - ciColor.red;
    CGFloat dg = ciColorOther.green - ciColor.green;
    CGFloat db = ciColorOther.blue - ciColor.blue;

    return sqrt(dr * dr + dg * dg + db * db);
}

@end
```

Swift:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    func euclideanDistance(to other: UIColor) -> CGFloat? {
        let ciColor = CIColor(color: self)
        let ciColorOther = CIColor(color: other)

        guard ciColor.numberOfComponents == ciColorOther.numberOfComponents,
            ciColor.alpha == 1.0, ciColorOther.alpha == 1.0 else {
                return nil;
        }

        let dr = ciColorOther.red - ciColor.red
        let dg = ciColorOther.green - ciColor.green
        let db = ciColorOther.blue - ciColor.blue

        return sqrt(dr * dr + dg * dg + db * db)
    }
}
```

- Display P3: (0.692708 0.220536 0.201643 1)
- Display P3: (0.692708 0.220536 0.198637 1)
- Euclidean distance: 0.0030061900627510133

We're able to calculate Euclidean distance of two colors, let's write a simple function to check if two colors matches with some tolerance:

Objective-C:

```c
@interface UIColor(Matching)

- (BOOL)matchesTo:(UIColor *)other;
- (BOOL)matchesTo:(UIColor *)other euclideanDistanceTolerance:(CGFloat)tolerance;

@end

@implementation UIColor(Matching)

- (BOOL)matchesTo:(UIColor *)other {
    return [self matchesTo:other euclideanDistanceTolerance:0.01];
}

- (BOOL)matchesTo:(UIColor *)other euclideanDistanceTolerance:(CGFloat)tolerance {
    CGFloat distance = [self euclideanDistanceTo:other];
    return distance <= tolerance;
}

@end
```

Swift:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    func matches(to other: UIColor, euclideanDistanceTolerance tolerance: CGFloat = 0.01) -> Bool? {
        guard let distance = euclideanDistance(to: other) else {
            return nil
        }

        return distance <= tolerance
    }
}
```

### All the pieces together

- I took a screenshot of your image
- Did open it in the Pixelmator and exported for web (sRGB, no profile associated)
- Dragged & dropped into the assets catalog
- Picked the red color (`#C02A2B`) from the image
- Did add `CustomRedColor` into the assets catalog

  - Gamut Any, Content sRGB, 8-bit Hexadecimal `#C02A2B`
- Made a simple view controller with tap gesture handler utilizing all the functions we have discussed

Objective-C:

```c
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *leftView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *rightView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.imageView];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceDisplayP3);
    if (colorSpace == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    UIColor *assetsCatalogRedColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"CustomRedColor"];
    UIColor *redColor = [assetsCatalogRedColor convertedToColorSpace:colorSpace];
    UIColor *tappedColor = [[self.imageView colorAt:location] convertedToColorSpace:colorSpace];

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    self.leftView.backgroundColor = tappedColor;
    self.rightView.backgroundColor = redColor;

    if (redColor == nil || tappedColor == nil) {
        return;
    }

    @try {
        BOOL matches = [tappedColor matchesTo:redColor];
        NSLog(@"Tapped color matches CustomRedColor: %@", matches ? @"true" : @"false");
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@", exception);
    }
}

@end
```

Swift:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var leftView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var rightView: UIView!

    private let assetsCatalogRedColor: UIColor = UIColor(named: "CustomRedColor")!

    @IBAction
    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: imageView)

        guard let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.displayP3),
            let redColor = assetsCatalogRedColor.converted(toColorSpace: colorSpace, intent: .defaultIntent),
            let tappedColor = imageView.color(at: location)?.converted(toColorSpace: colorSpace, intent: .defaultIntent) else {
                return
        }

        let matches = tappedColor.matches(to: redColor) ?? false

        print("Tapped color matches CustomRedColor: \(matches)")

        leftView.backgroundColor = tappedColor
        rightView.backgroundColor = redColor
    }
}
```

[image]

- Tapped the bottom red circle
- And I've got `Tapped color matches CustomRedColor: true`

### Conclusion

It's not that easy to get colors right (define, get, compare, convert, ...). Tried to point out important things while keeping it simple, but you should be able to do it now. Don't forget to correctly create a color, convert to a proper color space, pick a tolerance which suits your application needs, etc.

Here's the [public GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/zrzka/50ec9e78fd2326c4d6af2ba40b3e802e) which contains both Objective-C & Swift view controller implementations.

### Addendum

The color space conversion is not necessary, because the [`[UIColor getRed:green:blue:alpha:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621919-getred?language=objc) documentation says:

> If the color is in a compatible color space, the color is converted into RGB format and its components are returned to your application. If the color is not in a compatible color space, the parameters are unchanged.
>
> &
>
> red (green, blue) - On return, the red component of the color object. On applications linked for iOS 10 or later, the red component is specified in an extended range sRGB color space and can have any value. Values between 0.0 and 1.0 are inside the sRGB color gamut. On earlier versions of iOS, the specified value is always between 0.0 and 1.0.

Color component values should be converted for you if you use this function. But I kept the conversion code in this answer to demonstrate what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Truly incredible answer. Thoroughness unmatched, comprehensive and with specific examples. My thanks to you.